# Can Kafka be used for real time notification?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to understand how Kafka can be used for real time notification. Let's say I have a kafka topic for alerting purposes. This topic is used by various services to send updates to the users.

There are 10 instances of notification service running and consuming messages from the topic.

Online users would be distributed among 10 instances. For ex: User1 might be connected to Instance 8 with a websocket connection.

So how to ensure that users are notified correctly? That is, how to ensure that only Instance8 is processing the message for the User1.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem needs to be addressed through multiple angles - let's look at each one...

**First - the consumer side...**

You'll need as many partitions as there are consumer application instances i.e. the notification service - in your case you've got 10 instances so 10 partitions (or a multiple of 10) to the topic. This will ensure none of the service instances are left idle. Also, they'll need to be a part of the same consumer group. Now, there are a few different partition assignment approaches available and you might need to look into these to find out the one that suits your situation - here's a good [reference article](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3).

- An example - If you've got 100 users and `user-1` to `user-10` must be handled by `notification-service-1`, then [`StickyAssignor`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/StickyAssignor.html) might suit you best.
- Alternatively, you could even write your custom partition assignor and the reference article mentioned above does provide some information on this as well

**Second - the producer side...**

The producer applications writing data to the given Kafka topic should ensure that they send data related to a particular user to a certain partition.

As Kafka messages are made up of `key-value` pairs, you'll need to make sure that the keys are NOT `null`. The best would be to use some `user-related-information` as the `key` - this way you can make sure that messages in any partition are consumed by the designated consumer instance.

**Lastly**, please note that I've left out the part on which users (socket connections) are mapped to which notification service instance as it is beyond Kafka and I'm not sure if that part is designed to be strict or not.

Comment: I could guess this. But I did not want to maintain a sticky session between the user and the corresponding notification service instance. looks like there is no option.

Comment: My concern was - what if instance8 goes down.? In the suggested approach, user1 client app will wait for instance8 to come up to establish the session again.

Comment: Okay. So, if the notification-service-instance-{1-10} are not bound to be strict then you're good i.e. your design becomes much simpler. If an instance goes down, one of the other available instances will pick up the idle partitions until that instance comes back up. In this time, it will continue to serve those users.

Comment: you are not getting the point!! "it will continue to serve those users" - what is the guarantee? For ex: instance8 goes down. so websocket session will be killed. client-app will try to reestablish the connection. it might land on instance6. now what is the gurantee that instance6 is processing the partition for the users.

Comment: So, for this one you may need to write your own partition assignor (various ways to do this) if you need absolute predictability (consistency) and the order in which instances pick up idle partitions. The other option, if you don't want to write a custom partition assignor then you could trade availability for consistency i.e. the affected users stay disconnected until the expected service instance comes back up.

Comment: ok. understood.